# How to bring software console in Yocto

Tags: c++, arm, yocto

Here from point 1 to 11, it is mentioned how prebuilt image booted:

https://wiki.phytec.com/display/public/PRODUCTINFO/BSP+Yocto+FSL+i.MX7+PD18.1.x+Quickstart#BSPYoctoFSLi.MX7PD18.1.xQuickstart-GettingStartedWithBinaryImagesGettingStartedWithBinaryImages

I can see the booting info on terminal software, minicom.

I also have built complete image from its source and its behave same as prebuilt image mentioned here.

I have some application source files(c++/c) which compiled with x86 architecture in ubuntu/centos and generate an .exe file. This .exe file I can run in ubuntu/centos and that bring a console where I can give some inputs depending on what in source file written is.

But how such console( of .exe file corresponding to sources) can be brought over ARM Yocto linux system running on SD card.

As recipe I have already compiled the sources in ARM tool chain architecture and also append it to previously built image by adding IMAGE_INSTALL_append=" xyzlayer" in local.conf file and loaded onto SD card.

But What I don't understand how to bring console of application sources in ARM Yocto linux?

After booting the new image with appended sources, during linux booting console is same as without source and I don't know how it bring it here? Any help??

Comment: `of .exe file` -- what?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Lets say I have written a c++ code that take 2 inputs a and b and add them. When I compile this code and run the output file(.exe) it prompts for value of a and b and display the result. I mean this console to bring on Yocto system.

Comment: so you need a serial console or ssh?

Comment: linux booting info is already displayed on serial console(minicom) but don't know how to bring there what I have mentioned above. Any hints? or SSh way??

Comment: I have zero understanding of what you're trying to achieve. Try to rephrase your question.

Comment: Tell me how to bring hello world program over serial console/SSH in yocto?

Comment: you wanna transfer a binary file to a board?

Comment: Not just transfer but also run over it.

Comment: transfer it over ssh and run using shell over ssh or add the binary to the image and you'll have on the filesystem after boot, you have a console already.

Comment: This " add the binary to the image and you'll have on the filesystem after boot," I have already by following this as example http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Hello_World  but I don't know why hello world I don't see on console

Comment: "But What I don't understand how to bring console of application sources in ARM Yocto linux? - this sentence makes NO sense.

Comment: Ya, I have not formulated good way you are right. but you understood what I mean.

Comment: no, I don't understand what you are aiming for!

Comment: what i understand is that, you have a .exe file and when you run on ubuntu(x86), you get a console(application console).........and when you transfer the same .exe file to root filesystem(using yocto) and then run that .exe file on ARM based board....you dont get the same console(application console)....Is the understanding correct..?

Comment: Hi, Its my mistake. I also had to run the output file present in bin on the terminal which i didn't and I was directory expecting on that terminal application program output. When I run this output file on that terminal it works.